# Short proof for convergence in probability.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, weak-convergence

I saw a very short proof for convergence in probability implies convergence in distrubution. using a contradiction

Here it is:

Assume $X_n \to X$ in probabililty. And pick any $f\in C_b(\mathbb{R})$ (continious bounded function) such that $\mathbb{E}[f(X_n)] \not\to \mathbb{E}[f(X)]$

There exists a subsequence $n_k$ such that $X_{n_{k}} \to_{k\to \infty} X$ almost surely as $X_n $ converges in probability.

Then by the dominated convergence theorem as $f$ is bounded $\lim_{k\to\infty}\mathbb{E}[f(X_{n_k}] = \mathbb{E}[f(X)]$

Apparently this contradicts the fact that $\mathbb{E}[f(X_n)] \not\to \mathbb{E}[f(X)]$
but I cannot see how!

Any help would be great :)

Comment: It may be useful to internalize the fact that convergence in probability is sufficient for the dominated convergence theorem: If $Y_n\stackrel{P}{\to}Y$ and $|Y_n|\le Z\in L^1$ then $\lim_n \Bbb E[Y_n] =\Bbb E[Y]$. (Use the "double subsequence" principle.)

Comment: This was helpful John!

Something like this might work ? 

$X_n \to^P X$ then $f(X_n) \to ^P f(X)$ and $f(X_n) \leq M$ for some $M$ and so bounded convergence theorem gives the desired result!

Comment: Yes. Or maybe $|f(X_n)|\le M$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree, there seems to be a step missing.  Specifically, we need that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{E}[f(X_n)]$ exists for this proof to work.  To handle that, we can look at the limsup or liminf instead:

If $\mathbb{E}[f(X_n)] \not \rightarrow \mathbb{E}[f(X)]$, then $\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{E}[f(X_n)] \ne \mathbb{E}[f(X)]$ or $\liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{E}[f(X_n)] \ne \mathbb{E}[f(X)]$.  Suppose $\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{E}[f(X_n)] \ne \mathbb{E}[f(X)]$, and take a subsequence $n_k$ such that $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{E}[f(X_{n_k})] = \limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{E}[f(X_n)] \ne \mathbb{E}[f(X)]$.  Now take a further subsequence $n_{k_m}$ such that $X_{n_{k_m}} \rightarrow X$ a.s.  By the dominated convergence theorem, $\lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{E}[f(X_{n_{k_m}})] = \mathbb{E}[f(X)]$, which contradicts $\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{E}[f(X_{n_k})] \ne \mathbb{E}[f(X)]$.

Comment: This was really helpful!